# Sortable HashMap-like data structure in Java?

Tags: java, sorting, data-structures, hashmap, associative-array

Is there some sort of data structure in Java that resembles a HashMap that can be sorted by key or value?   In PHP you can have associative arrays that are sortable.  Is there such a thing in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`HashMap`s are unsorted almost by definition; a good hash function will produce a seemingly random distribution of the keys.

If you want to use a `Map` in Java that stores its elements in sorted order, consider looking into `TreeMap`, which is backed by a sorted binary search tree.

If you want something that can be sorted either by key or by value, you may be looking for a bidirectional map or "bimap."  Java doesn't have on in its standard libraries, and the closest implementation I know of is [Google's `BiMap`](http://google-collections.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/javadoc/com/google/common/collect/BiMap.html).  However, as Pangea pointed out, it does not support elements in sorted order.  You could easily make your own implementation by just using two `TreeMap`s, though, one from keys to values and one from values to keys.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I doesn't think BiMap supports sorted keys or values

Comment: @Pangea- I didn't know that; thanks for pointing this out.  I've updated my answer accordingly.

Answer (score 4):

[SortedMap](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/SortedMap.html) sorted only by keys