# Android: How can i sort HashMap by values from two sources?

Tags: android, sorting, hashmap, browser-history

I have created a records based on date, name and url from default browser and google chrome. I combine the history information based on the two browser and display it using Hashmap. So now what i am trying to do is I would like to do a sort by date and also by name. However, due to my knowledge i am facing difficulties implementing it. Any advice and suggestions will be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance.

```
//default browser
if (mCur.moveToFirst() && mCur.getCount() > 0) {
        int titleIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
        int urlIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);
        int dateIdx = mCur.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE);

        while (mCur.isAfterLast() == false) {
            HashMap temp = new HashMap();
            temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN,getDate(mCur.getLong(dateIdx), "dd/MM/yyyy   HH:mm:ss      "));
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, mCur.getString(titleIdx));
            temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, mCur.getString(urlIdx));
            list.add(temp);
            mCur.moveToNext();
        }
    }
    //google chrome
    if (mCur2.moveToFirst() && mCur2.getCount() > 0) {
        int dateIdx2 = mCur2.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.DATE);
        int titleIdx2 = mCur2.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.TITLE);
        int urlIdx2 = mCur2.getColumnIndex(Browser.BookmarkColumns.URL);

        while (mCur2.isAfterLast() == false) {
            HashMap temp = new HashMap();
            temp.put(FIRST_COLUMN, getDate(mCur2.getLong(dateIdx2), "dd/MM/yyyy   HH:mm:ss      "));
            temp.put(SECOND_COLUMN, mCur2.getString(titleIdx2));
            temp.put(THIRD_COLUMN, mCur2.getString(urlIdx2));
            list.add(temp);
            mCur2.moveToNext();
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a Model class for your data with sorting comparators like below:

```
public class MyItem {
String title;
String url;
String date;

public MyItem(String title, String url, String date) {
    this.title = title;
    this.url = url;
    this.date = date;
}

public static Comparator<MyItem> sortByDate = new Comparator<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyItem item1, MyItem item2) {
        return item1.date.compareTo(item2.date);
    }
};

public static Comparator<MyItem> sortByTitle = new Comparator<MyItem>() {
    @Override
    public int compare(MyItem item1, MyItem item2) {
        return item1.title.compareTo(item2.title);
    }
};
```

}

Then use it like this in your code
Create a list/array of Myitems
then call the function to sort => Arrays.sort(yourMyItemsObject, MyItem.sortByTitle);

Change the code of compare() Method as per your need of sort.

Answer (score 0):

Use Inner class concept for sorting the hash map, dont use two hash map,

First sort the hash map of class level and then sort the hash value, by this in the same hash map you will get the both sorted value

Comment: Inner class concept?

Answer (score 0):

Look at [Sortable HashMap-like data structure in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5113688/sortable-hashmap-like-data-structure-in-java) for using sortable HashMap like data structures.

You'll need to combine all data into one Map object and then sort it just before you want to display the result to the user.

good luck